# In App Purchases - Receipt Validation: status = 21004

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am working on Receipt Validation for a subscription In App Purchase for my application. I am Using **SwiftyReceiptValidator** files from this github project:

https://github.com/crashoverride777/SwiftyReceiptValidator/tree/master/SwiftyReceiptValidator

to help me with my receipt validation.

in my code I'm using:

```
SwiftyReceiptValidator.validate(forIdentifier: "MyProductId", sharedSecret: "MyCorrectSharedSecret") { (bool: Bool, dict: [String : AnyObject]?) in

}
```

when I try to validate my product I'm getting **status = 21004** which means incorrect SharedSecret Key. But I am 100% sure that my Shared Secret is correct as I copied and pasted it directly from itunes connect.

**Question:**

Is This error for sure caused by SharedSecret Key? Or could this be caused by something else?

**Output when executing the code above**

Receipt found

Starting receipt validation

Receipt validation failed: URL request - Invalid receipt status in json response = 21007

Receipt validation failed: Production url used in sandbox mode, trying sandbox url...

Receipt validation failed: URL request - Invalid receipt status in json response = 21004

Receipt validation failed: Status = 21004

Comment: I'm facing same issue. SwiftyStoreKit.verifyReceipt returns 21004 error. I'm also using correct SharedSecret key. did you get luck on this? thank you

Comment: @Prakhar no luck yet. Still working through the problem. Ill let you know when I find a solution

Comment: @Prakhar, this was a bug with Apple. Seems to be fixed now. Check out the answer below.

Comment: Yup! I just checked. I was going to inform you same. :-P Thanks mate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be fixed right now

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/72991

Comment: Thank you! I will attempt this again and let you know if it is working.